Is it possible to install spaCy models using a different C++ compiler
I am trying to install a spaCy model:
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz

and getting the following error:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

I do have a GCC compiler installed that is being recognized by the PATH:
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 12.3.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Is it possible to make pip use gcc?
EDIT:
The C++ compiler I am using comes with RTools and is installed at C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/gcc

If you install MinGW, pip and python using msys2 and use the gcc and python from msys2 you shouldn't have this compiler issue. https://packages.msys2.org/packages/python-pip?variant=x86_64

With that said I did get a different warning about manually installing packages using pip instead of the python system packages that pacman manages.

I added that the C/C++ compilers were installed via RTools.
